# The Great MAF Experiment

Tags: discussion

***Keep on reading if you have access to an OBD-II reader and a fuel-injected vehicle***

---

As mentioned in [this meta post](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1844/i-want-to-crowd-source-data-on-maf-readings-at-idle-should-i-make-the-request-o), I'm on a mission to collect data for mass air flow values at idle. With sufficient data, it should be possible to post an informed, objective response to the [volumetric efficiency rule-of-thumb](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/33549/675) question.

It should take no longer than 15 minutes to obtain the readings, fill out the questionnaire and send it over. All results will be aggregated on Google Forms.

---

### [Here is the questionnaire](https://goo.gl/forms/Tmaeql1TcXW6nWYi2) (Google Forms)

### [Here is the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50622/the-great-maf-experiment) dedicated to this endeavour

---

***Questions***

1. Mechanics.SE Username (self-explanatory, optional)
2. Vehicle Make, Model, Year (comma-separated values are fine)
3. Engine Type (gasoline or diesel, naturally aspirated or forced induction)
4. Engine Size (how big is the engine, in liters?)
5. What was the OBD-II readout for idle RPM with vehicle stationary?
6. Was the air-conditioning on?
7. Do you know if the engine use a mass air flow (MAF) sensor or manifold absolute pressure (MAP) sensor to provide the OBD-II readout?
8. What was the OBD-II readout for mass air flow?
9. What were the units for the mass air flow OBD-II readout?
10. How old is/are the MAF/MAP sensor(s)?

---

Don't forget to hit **<kbd>Submit</kbd>** and thank you for your time!

All information provided will be made public at the end of this survey.

---

***Additional notes/clarifications***

- **Please take the readings with the engine at operating temperature.** If you are unable to do so for whatever reason, please mention it in the "Other comments/remarks" field
- It is OK to post the expected values *from an official service manual* in lieu of logging data via OBD-II and the value(s) are in units of mass / time
- a generic Bluetooth/Wi-Fi OBD-II reader should be sufficient for logging the requested information
- This questionnaire is applicable for *both* gasoline and diesel engine vehicles
- It is not mandatory to take RPM/MAF readings with the A/C both on *and* off, but if you do that counts for two datum points
- Exact engine displacement is not critical, advertised engine displacement ought to be sufficient (4.991 L vs 5.0 L)

Comment: Is it good enough to give the expected values from the work shop manual?  the WSM for my 98 mazda 626 2L has expected MAF values at idle both with and without A/C on.  The wsm for my 99 Nissan Almera 1.6L might have also.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes that should be fine as long as it is in the official workshop manual and the values are in mass flow per unit time

Comment: At least for the Mazda the units are grams per second.  Not sure about the Nissan, I'll have to check.

Comment: Very good, sir!

Comment: @ZachMierzejewski yes, a generic Bluetooth based OBD-II reader will give you back this information

Comment: @Zaid I deleted my comment because I found the answer implied in your [question](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/33549/675).  But for posterity, it was: Can I find `8. ... OBD-II readout for mass air flow ...` with a cheap, generic OBD-II scanner?

Comment: Are you interested in diesel values?

Comment: I will see if I can contribute with three cars this coming weekend ... as long as my reader will cooperate with the right values. Also, would you want stated displacement, or actual displacement. Remember, there was a question a few weeks ago which garnered a lot of attention for this ... A Ford 5.0L engine doesn't *exactly* displace 5.0L, but more like 4942 cc's. You may want to clarify this in your question.

Comment: @dlu absolutely interested in diesels! They're definitely in scope

Comment: Say, I don't know if it is too late to change the form, but it might be worth adding fields for the method used to read the data. For example I would report something like "VCDS-Mobile N-M" (or however it is that they specify the group and item). Also, I don't have any idea how old my MAF sensor is (other than maybe 11 years), how do you want that reported?

Comment: Do you want us to get both A/C on and A/C off readings?

Comment: @dlu what you use to take the reading isn't really that critical in my opinion, but you mention it in the "Other Comments" section. Regarding MAF age, you can specify the "Never changed in my ownership" option

Comment: @dlu if you can readings with both A/C on and off that would be great since it would give us two datums, but I don't want to impose it on others

Comment: Easy enough to do, the hard part is getting myself to dig out the scanner and go out in the cold and dark :-) Do you care if the engine is up to operating temperature or not?

Comment: @dlu hmm, that is a good question. I don't want to muck around with cold-start enrichment, so please let the engine warm up before you take readings

Comment: On my cars it is easy to get the temperature of both the engine and the intake air (I think) with the scanner. Would either be helpful? Does MAF already include a compensation for air temperature?

Comment: @dlu a true MAF reading should already account for temperature, so no need for that.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I don't consider the exact displacement as something critical for the purposes of this study. Advertised displacement is fine.

Comment: Block heaters on and engine is warming up, looking for the scan tool in my newly organized shop…

Comment: Just checked, and unfortunately the WSM and tools for the 99 Almera only give voltages without specifying any specific units.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes oh well, appreciate your checking though

Comment: why the maf/no maf field? usually when people talk about ve it's about maf ve as speed density cars don't suffer from ve problems unless theres a mechanical issue. either way i probably have a lot of saved data i'll have to go through it.

Comment: I'm also curious as to why only at idle? Why not at peak RPM and peak maf gm/s as well? You'd want to know intake air temperature as well.

Comment: @Ben I chose idle over peak RPM/WOT  for a few reasons. It's easier to perform the test so I expect more people will be able to contribute data, it serves as a more consistent baseline in terms of engine load ("zero" load), and it is difficult to obtain stable readings for the max mass flow rate because it doesn't last very long. My understanding is that if the MAF is a true mass air flow reading IAT should be redundant (it's used for calculating other parameters). I was also considering adding altitude to the survey as well but decided against it because the goal here is to find a rough rule.

Comment: @Ben regarding the MAF/no MAF question, I requested it for better data segregation/classification. No other reason.

Comment: I think you want IAT so you can roughly calculate air density. Either way I'll submit something before I go to bed.

Comment: Do you want the minimum, maximum, or average value over a period of time?

Comment: @JasonC You'll see that the reading fluctuates a little. The average is most representative in my opinion

Comment: @Ben ***thank you so much*** for your contributions to the data set. I have some questions/comments regarding the data provided in the [dedicated chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50622/the-great-maf-experiment). Hopefully it shouldn't take too long to answer them.

Comment: My car uses a map sensor. The mass airflow obd value is not available. I can only get intake manifold pressure in psi (or kpa, etc.). Is that at all useful?

Comment: @JasonC let's discuss in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50622/the-great-maf-experiment)

Comment: Wondering how this was going, I kind of forgot after a point. I have some other saved data if you still need more.

Comment: @Ben sorry for the late reply. The minimum requirement for analysis has been met, but if you could share more data that would be great. It would be helpful if you can indicate whether the vehicle has known breathing issues (things like vacuum leak, faulty IAC, etc)

Comment: Is this still a thing? Based on the chat room I just found, it seems so? And are you interested in this data from modified vehicles? My Subaru has some aftermarket parts and a custom ECU tune which potentially have affected some of the values which would differ from stock. I have an AccessPort, so I could probably get you a variety of readings. I think I can add intake temp.

Comment: @Ellesedil please do contribute. If it is a turbo engine I hope you have access to a boost gauge (or readout) please include it in the comments/additional notes. I have a fairly good sample size for naturally aspirated gasoline engines... just haven't found the time to write it up as an answer. The findings are summarized in chat.

Comment: My AccessPort can record boost pressure. It actually provides a large amount of different values that I can record. https://cobb.app.box.com/v/subaru-monitor-list  Looks like MAF is in g/s, and there's also a MAF Voltage parameter, along with intake temp, manifold pressure (should be at vacuum at idle of course), and engine speed. If there's anything else that tickles your fancy, let me know. My car is actually getting a new dyno tune tomorrow, but I'll try to remember to grab this data for you afterwards.

Answer (score 9):

I think the same caveats exist that existed months ago.

I feel Intake air temperature is vital for this experiment.  A so-called "MAF" really isn't.  It's a *guessmatic predicticator prognostitron (tm)* of flow *based on cooling of a hot wire, or hot film* (better).  This "voltage" or "frequency" rise may be non-linear, and further scaled by the ECU based on actual factory testing with all relevant plumbing in place.

I suggest you are making a number of assumptions about air temperature, humidity, density, as well as an assumed stoich at idle [maybe?] but I wonder if this is still true on GDI IC.  I think there is a component of combustion that ultimately affects VE, albiet not directly.  "Load" comes to mind.

Another issue is the associated plumbing before the MAF; it's a well-known caveat of installing aftermarket Cold Air Intake systems, which change the factory tested flow, and also change the response in the very narrow region of the hot wire or film, and can cause a vehicle to run lean and/or with high fuel trims.

For useful apples-apples comparisons, I think the only VE data that's useful is under signifigant load.  Otherwise, who cares about VE at idle?

Besides the GDI issue, you might also want to restrict this to Normally Aspirated vehicles.  VE goes out the window with any sort of supercharging. (In a good way, I admit.)  There won't be any boost at idle, at least on turbosupercharged vehicles, including diesels.

There are simply too many variables, including ECU software implementations, calibrated intake plumbing, variable intake devices, and AFR strategies.

I don't want to discourage a noble effort, but I'm just not seeing the point.  There's no way you can compare the VE of a Subaru turbo 2.5 EJ205 to a Honda VTEC 1.7 at *Idle* and have data that is useful.  BOTH engines have characteristics (turbo, VTEC) that change VE based on rpm and/or load.

The only useful data would be an additional plot on a dyno chart showing MAF values vs. RPM, along with the intake air temp, density, humidty, and other appropos corrections.

Still, I'll run my 1996 and newer vehicles and see if they correlate to any real meaning.  Most of my fleet is pre-OBD2, which is a shame because I'd love to know the VE baseline of my '72 BMW 2002tii M10 racing engine.

Comment: Thanks for supporting this initiative. I thought long and hard about whether to include IAT in the survey but decided against it for [a few reasons](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1857/the-great-maf-experiment?cb=1#comment3460_1857)

Comment: Not saying that I'm 100% sure I don't need it, but I didn't want to burden the survey participants with Yet Another OBD2 Parameter™

Answer (score 6):

### Here is a sample response for one of my cars

1. Zaid
2. BMW, M5, 1999
3. Gasoline, naturally aspirated
4. 5.0
5. 613 RPM
6. No
7. MAF
8. 19.00
9. kg/h
10. Less than 2 years old

---

***Based on this screenshot***

[image: Sample OBD-II readout]